# Get all the documents in a collection along with the path of the document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all the documents in a collection along with the corresponding document paths. I can use something like this to get all the document paths:

```
firestore.collection("root_collection").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getPath());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

However, after this I'll have to make n(number of documents in collection) reads to fetch these documents, which will cost me a lot more than fetching them as a collection in a single read.

Comment: When you query a collection like this, you are actually getting the contents of all the documents in that collection.  There's no need to make another query - everything is already in each QueryDocumentSnapshot that you receive.

Comment: You can follow this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_1) and replace the .collection("cities") with your root_collection.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after this I'll have to make n(number of documents in the collection) reads to fetch these documents, which will cost me a lot more than fetching them as a collection in a single read.

In order to create a list of document paths, you create "n" requests. To actually get the content of all the corresponding documents, you do another "n" request according to the newly created list. Why would you do that? If you need to get the documents together with their paths, why not to get them using a single request? So please check the following approach:

```
firestore.collection("root_collection").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
            List<ModelClass> documents = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                paths.add(document.getPath());
                documents.add(document.toObject(ModelClass.class));
            }

            //Do what you need to do with the lists
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Otherwise, that would be a waste of document reads.

Answer (score 0):

When you query a collection like this, you are actually getting the entire contents of **all** the documents in that collection.  There's no need to make another query - everything is already in each QueryDocumentSnapshot that you receive.  Note that [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot) subclasses [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot).  You can simply call its getter methods to know the contents of the document.  For example, you can call `document.getData()` to get a Map of the entire document contents.